# When writing section of txt-file to csv, each single character is assigned a new column for each line

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have made a program, that reads all the lines of a textfile, and then finds the part of the line, where a specific string ends with Kbits. For all lines that this occurs I take the part that comes right before Kbits (which is an int) and puts it into a list, which I later write to a csv-file. The problem is, that when I write to the csv-file, the Int is split up, and each number is assigned to a new column in the csv-file. I have an idea that is has something to do with the way I typecast, but I can't figure it out. 
I am using Python 2.7.

A line in the txt-file would be something like this:

```
[2018-01-24 14:57:05,766] [  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   872 KBytes  7140 Kbits/sec  2.714 ms  693/1326 (52%)
```

And for this specific line I want to have a `7140` in my .csv file

My code is as follows:

```
lst = []
myfile = file('file.csv', 'wb')
txtfile = open('file.txt')

for line in txtfile:
    line = str(re.findall('\d*\ Kbits', line))
    if(line == "[]"):
        r = 1
    else:
        new = line.replace(" Kbits", "")
        lst.append(new)

wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    wr.writerow(lst[i])
txtfile.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide some input strings and what you want in your `.csv` file? Just edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import re
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open('file.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row in f_input:
        kbits = re.findall('(\d+)\ Kbits', row)

        if kbits:
            csv_output.writerow(kbits)
```

For your example line `file.csv` would look like:

```
"7140"
```

Comment: I can get that output too, the problem occurs when I only want the number part. so instead of "7140 Kbits" I want to have just "7140", also note that some of the lines in the full .txt file do not containt a line with "Kbits".

Comment: You just need to use `(\d+)`, I have updated the script.

Comment: thank you, that worked. I think I might have overcomplicated this in the first place.